# How to activate WiFi when it says "disabled by hardware switch"?

Tags: wireless, networking

I have VAIO VPCEA23EN with Ubuntu 12.04 32 Bit.

Bluetooth is working but not WiFi.
It says "disabled by hardware switch" even when it's enabled.

Comment: You tried toggling the wifi switch? Also did you check to see if wifi is enabled in bios? Also, did you check System Settings > Additional Drivers?

Comment: if you want help, you need to tell us what kind of wireless card you have, not what kind of computer you have.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I fix a "Wireless is disabled by hardware switch" error?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/139036/how-do-i-fix-a-wireless-is-disabled-by-hardware-switch-error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the terminal. the shortcut is:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

Then type this command:

```
sudo rfkill unblock all
```

If it did not work from the beginning.Try typing it again like 2 or 3 times and then see

Sometimes the hard switch won't work. So this command works like a hard switch and helps enabling the Wifi.

Comment: that won't help if it's reading as disabled by hardware switch

Comment: Thanks for Down-voting my solution. I guess if you have a better solution you can Lighten us with it :)

Comment: @Suhaib - I've up-voted it...

Comment: @Suhaib - No problem...

Answer (score 0):

I have seen similar behaviour with my Dell E5430.  If the machine is booted with the hardware switch in the off position, then toggling it does nothing, and the wireless interface cannot be activated until the machine is rebooted with the switch in the 'on' position.

Once this is done - the hard switch works as expected - powering the wireless card up and down.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem with my asus x550c notebook none of the above answers helped but I have found that if I boot up and log in then close the lid  and then open the lid again when I log in again the wi fi will be working hope this helps other users