# trying to get wifi on dell inspiron-1764

Tags: wireless

I have a Dell Inspiron-1764.  I just installed ubuntu 13.10. I am new to ubuntu so I really don't know any commands.  I think ubuntu can't read my drivers..

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem, try with this

```
rfkill unblock all
```

Source:[How do I fix a "Wireless is disabled by hardware switch" error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/139036/how-do-i-fix-a-wireless-is-disabled-by-hardware-switch-error)

Answer (score 0):

Your question does not state the exact problem you are facing but still...

You may want to check if there are any Drivers update available...You can check this by typing "***Additional Drivers***" in Dash Board search bar and clicking on the result..If it shows the available update then install it..

Or If it does not work then you can go for [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-install-broadcom-wireless-drivers-bcm43xx)

Comment: Ubuntu won't detect wifi.  I am new to this.

Comment: Exactly! you should try and install the Drivers(if available). If not then go to the link provided in the answer..