# Unable to connect to wifi on ASUS K401UB laptop

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers, 16.04, asus

I bought a new laptop (ASUS K401UB). Now, I am encountering a problem with the wifi.

1. During installation, I was able to detect wifi networks but when I select my wifi, Ubuntu replaces the contents with a text "qualcom atheros..." or so.
2. Ignoring the selection of wifi, I decided to proceed with the installation but after successfully booting to Ubuntu, **Enable Wireless** menu is disabled.

[image: Picture is from google]

3. So, I went to System Settings > **Network** to enable the Wireless but it just wont.
4. Then, I've tried to google the issue and found these links:

   1. [How do I fix a "Wireless is disabled by hardware switch" error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/139036/how-do-i-fix-a-wireless-is-disabled-by-hardware-switch-error)
   2. [Kittinan: How to install Ubuntu 14.04 on Asus K401UB](https://kittinanx.blogspot.com/2016/04/how-to-install-ubuntu-1404-on-asus-k401u.html)
5. I found a way to enable the wifi and that is to press <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>f1</kbd>. I don't why.
6. I find it annoying to do **(5.)** every time I restart; so I decided to follow the instruction in **4.1 [How do I fix a "Wireless is disabled by hardware switch" error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/139036/how-do-i-fix-a-wireless-is-disabled-by-hardware-switch-error)**
7. Doing `rfkill list all` will show me:

   `Wifi: Wireless LAN:
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes`

   and `rfkill unblock all` results will still be the same.

My question is, is there any way to fix this issue? (Please see my LAN driver details below).

[image: Wifi Driver Details]

I have tried using both Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, and right now I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. But both of them have the same problem with the laptop. I contacted ASUS for this issue but they wont give support on Linux. The WIFI is the only problem I have right now. Please help.

P.S. What USB Wireless Adapters can you recommend for Linux users?

[image: operating system]

Comment: Did you try this? http://askubuntu.com/questions/351594/wireless-disabled-by-hardware-switch-on-an-asus-x550v/351860#351860

Comment: @chili555 thank you!!! can you please put your comment as answer instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the module *asus_nb_wmi* loaded? Check:

```
lsmod | grep asus
```

If so, please try a driver parameter:

```
sudo -i
echo "options asus_nb_wmi wapf=0" > /etc/modprobe.d/asus.conf
exit
```

Reboot and see if the Fn+F2 behavior is changed.

If the above does not work, redo it again but replace `asus_nb_wmi wapf=0` with `asus_nb_wmi wapf=1`, and if that does not work, replace it with `asus_nb_wmi wapf=4` instead.