# RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter - wifi not working on 14.04

Tags: networking, wireless

Here is my WIFI info script output:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/24586888/

Comment: Please refer to https://askubuntu.com/questions/635625/how-do-i-get-a-realtek-rtl8723be-wireless-card-to-work for possible solution

Answer (score 0):

As answers in this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/139036/how-do-i-fix-a-wireless-is-disabled-by-hardware-switch-error) suggest, two major kinds of kill switches handle the activity of any wifi radio- A hard/hardware switch and a soft/software switch.

Several options are available for turning software switch on, one that makes use of rfkill might be most helpful of them all. Launch terminal by "Ctrl+Alt+T" and run in the following code (type in the password for root if asked for):

```
sudo rfkill unblock all
```

Since your error log shows that hard switch is not the problem, but still in absence of any visible hardware switch (usually a button), you could try a dirty old trick. Just remove the battery from the case of your computer for few minutes, open up the lid if you haven't already as if you were to start the computer without a battery, press the power button for few seconds (usually 30 seconds would do). Then, reinsert the battery and power your computer on. See if the problem is resolved.