# Wifi disconnecting on closing screen of laptop

Tags: networking, dual-boot, wireless, 20.04, wifi-hardware-switch

As soon as I close the screen,

Wifi gets disconnected

and if I try to reconnect it, it shows **Hardware disabled error** as shown below:

[image: Image as shown below]

I have tried the solution given in [disabled by hardware switch](https://askubuntu.com/questions/139036/how-do-i-fix-a-wireless-is-disabled-by-hardware-switch-error) but failed to resolve it.

The only option left with me is to reboot the system

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had the same problem, this has solved it: https://tipsonubuntu.com/2018/04/28/change-lid-close-action-ubuntu-18-04-lts/

`sudo gedit /etc/systemd/logind.conf`
Finding `HandleLidSwitch` there and edit to:
`HandleLidSwitch=ignore`

Answer (score 0):

press f2 or any other key with airplane or signal symbol and try disabling auto disable wifi to save power from settings power

Comment: I have tried all the options but failed to resolve it.