# My wireless(WCN685X) not work from ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless

[image: lshw]

[image: lspci]

[image: ifconfig]

As mentioned above（Ubuntu 22.04）, my computer's display driver is already installed, but the wireless network device cannot be displayed. It will show unclaimed(ubuntu 20.04).but the bt driver works well which is in a same chip.And on the Windows platform, it works very well.So i need your help.thanks.

I'm not sure if I need to wait an official firmware update to support my device, or if, like the method mentioned [in the link,](https://askubuntu.com/questions/139036/how-do-i-fix-a-wireless-is-disabled-by-hardware-switch-error) can make my network card work with certain settings

Comment: Does this issue still happen on 21.10? You're using an unsupported beta release of Ubuntu, so try with the latest stable version (Ubuntu 21.10), and see if the issue still happens. If it goes away, file a bug report. Otherwise, report back and we can try to help

Comment: yes, it's still not work on 21.10, the information above is collected on 22.04(a beta version)， wireless driver shows UNCLAIMED from 20.04 to 21.10, so i try to use a beta version, but problem is still here.

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 doesn't yet exist; it's currently the *development* release Ubuntu *jammy* and remains that until it reaches RC state which isn't expected until after 14 April 2022, and isn't on-topic here until release on 21 April 2022.  https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/jammy-jellyfish-release-schedule/23906  Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic.  For support issues with Ubuntu *jammy* you'll need to use a #ubuntu-next or #ubuntu+1 site (IRC, UF etc)

Comment: If you wish to report bugs, firstly thank you for helping test the release, but please see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs and use a #ubuntu+1 site such as IRC, https://ubuntuforums.org/ etc.  This site isn't tracked for ubuntu+1 or #ubuntu-next issues.   Ubuntu *jammy* is still in **alpha** with the *beta* still scheduled to be reached on 28 March 2022.  https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/jammy-jellyfish-release-schedule/23906

Comment: I'm sorry, but what i want to say is my wireless still not work on ubuntu 22.04，Neither 20.04 nor 21.10, i can't find ubuntu version to support my device. so i don't think #ubuntu-next is suitable

Comment: it works well with linux-kernel-5.15.0-23-generic，thanks everyone.